# ShareKit 2.0: Getting OAuth Exception 368 on Facebook

Tags: ios, facebook, oauth, sharekit

I'm trying to post to Facebook using ShareKit 2.0.

I get the permission dialog, see the message UI pre filled with the default message I set in code - so far, so good.

When I click "Send to Facebook", I get an OAuth Exception 368 "The action attempted has been deemed abusive or is otherwise disallowed"

I assume it's a configuration issue on developers.facebook.com - I have set

Display Name
Namespace (do I actually need that?)
Contact Email
Category
iOS Bundle ID
iPhone app store ID
Configured for iOS SSO - Enabled
iOS Native Deep Linking - Enabled
URL Scheme Suffix

Auth Dialog settings are default (empty)

Advanced Settings:
App Type - Native/Desktop
Sandbox Mode: Disabled
Everything else is default/empty.

Any ideas?

UPDATE:

So, the problem seemed to be the URL to the app on the App Store within the pre-filled message, which led to the "abusive/disallowed" error. If I'm removing this URL, Facebook accepts even the pre-filled message.

Just using text messages works:

```
SHKItem *item = [SHKItem text:text];
```

The new question is - if I cannot have the URL in the text, how do I deal with services that do not have links to the originating app, like Twitter using ShareKit?

If I'm using

```
    SHKItem *item = [SHKItem URL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://itunes.com/apps/MyApp"] title:text contentType:SHKURLContentTypeWebpage];
```

Facebook will give me the same "abusive/disallowed" error (although visible to the user in the popup-WebView, and not as a request error).

Other URLs (not linking to the App Store) work.

My quick fix is to link to my own website, which describes the app and has an App Store badge, but probably this is not the best solution?

Comment: Have you tried it _without_ a pre-filled message …?

Comment: Ahem - interestingly enough, it's working with an empty NSString as pre-filled message. 

So, is that what's supposed to be happening? The pre-filled message is working for Twitter, but not for Facebook? (I just tried out these 2 services)